# Algebra - How do I answer this?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ , and let $L$ be a line in $\mathbb{R}^n$ . Show that $T(L)$ is also a line. (Is it not enough to just consider lines in the plane?)

Comment: Doesn't need to be. It can be just $\{0\}$.

Comment: @PeterFranek, I think the question may be referring to "generalized" lines in vector spaces: spans of one single vector, thus $\;\{0\}\;$ would qualify as a "line".

Comment: I would object to calling {0} a line...

Answer (score 5):

Half-formally, here is an explanation:
If L is a line, every $x \in L$ is of the form $x_0 + \lambda d$, where $\lambda \in \Bbb R,$ and $ x_0,d \in \Bbb R^n$.

$T$ is linear, therefore
$$T(x) = T(x_0 + \lambda d) = T(x_0) + \lambda T(d) = y_0 + \lambda \hat{d} $$
So you can see, that the $T(L)$ is also a "Line".

Comment: Short and to the point. +1